# How to link two sentences properly?

Tags: creative-writing, style, technique, formatting, structure

I have two sentences:

1. In general, the better the equipment, the higher quality of
   production you will end up with.
2. We choose our equipment very carefully.

To link them together, I have to use the word "hence", but I am not sure if that's the most appropriate. It comes out as:

> In general, the better the equipment, the higher quality of production
>   you will end up with. Hence, we choose our equipment very carefully.

Comment: "This is why", "Because of this", "Therefore"

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is asking for help writing a sentence.

Comment: "In general, the better the equipment, the higher quality of production you will end up with. At Company X, we know this, so we choose our equipment very carefully."

Comment: This could be the time to invoke the power of the semicolon! "In general, the better the equipment, the higher quality of production you will end up with; we choose our equipment very carefully."